# Change the structure of database using sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

My app is already in market now i want to add an extra column in table,as i studied i found onUpgrade() method in which i can add that column with ALTER TABLE and increasing my database version but the confusion is will this work without loosing any previous data when user get the notification for updating application, If yes, then what about new user if they will install the app for the first time will this onUpgrade() method will work for them the column will be added or only onCreate() method will work for them.

Comment: Use the Room library... It has a facility for this. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **will this work without loosing any previous data when user get the
>   notification for updating application?**

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN column_definition
```

Adds the column to the table as it is i.e. existing data will be retained (see extra below for an example).

However, there are some restrictions  as per :-

> The ADD COLUMN syntax is used to add a new column to an existing
>   table.
>
> The new column is always appended to the end of the list of
>   existing columns.
>
> The column-def rule defines the characteristics of
>   the new column.
>
> The new column may take any of the forms permissible
>   in a CREATE TABLE statement, with the following restrictions:
>
> - The column may not have a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint.
> - The column may not have a default value of CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, or an expression in parentheses.
> - If a NOT NULL constraint is specified, then the column must have a default value other than NULL.
> - If foreign key constraints are enabled and a column with a REFERENCES clause is added, the column must have a default value of
>     NULL.
>
> Note also that when adding a CHECK constraint, the CHECK constraint is
>   not tested against preexisting rows of the table. This can result in a
>   table that contains data that is in violation of the CHECK constraint.
>   Future versions of SQLite might change to validate CHECK constraints
>   as they are added.
>
> The execution time of the ALTER TABLE command is independent of the
>   amount of data in the table. The ALTER TABLE command runs as quickly
>   on a table with 10 million rows as it does on a table with 1 row.
>
> After ADD COLUMN has been run on a database, that database will not be
>   readable by SQLite version 3.1.3 (2005-02-20) and earlier.

From [ALTER TABLE](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

> **what about new user if they will install the app for the first time
>   will this onUpgrade() method will work for them the column will be
>   added or only onCreate() method will work for them?**

To cater for new users the Table Create as used in `onCreate` should include the new column as the new/increased database version will be in the APK so `onUpgrade` will not be invoked (it will be for existing users as the database exists and will have a/the previous version). However, the database (assuming it's not included as an asset) will not exist and therefore be created, thus resulting in the `onCreate` method running.

---

#### Extra

If you provide a `DEFAULT` then that value will be used to populate the column for all rows (see restrictions). e.g. :-

```
ALTER TABLE details ADD COLUMN testadd TEXT DEFAULT 'rumplestiltskin'
```

results in :-

[image]

- Existing data retained.
- Added column **testadd** populated with the default.

Comment: thnxx for your guidance......is this the right way---------------------------             if (newversion == 21) { sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("ALTER TABLE list ADD Column like"); } and in on create of databasedb.execSql("CREATE table list (COL_A, COL_B, like);......will it work???

Comment: Yes in principle

Answer (score 0):

You just add if statements for each version

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
        // This inner check isn't completely necessary if you can perform all upgrades in one step 
        if (newVersion == 2 && oldVersion == 1) {
            migrate1To2(db);  // TODO: Implement
        }
    } else {
        // DROP 
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: if (newversion == 21) {
                sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("ALTER TABLE list ADD Column like");
            } and in on create of databasedb.execSql("CREATE table list (COL_A, COL_B, like);......will it work

Comment: I think you need to give a type to the columns, but there's nothing to alter when you created the table with that column already

Answer (score 0):

Typically, in the `onUpgrade()` method a developer would follow this pattern:

- Dropping the old tables
- Creating a new table by calling `onCreate()`

For your question, I'd suggest you add the column in the `onCreate()` method rather than the `onUpgrade()` and use the `onUpgrade()` as follows:

- Firstly, alter the table name of the previously created table (table1) in `onCreate()` to table2.

  `ALTER TABLE table1 RENAME TO table2`
- Call the `onCreate()` method again to create the table (table1) with an added column name of your choice.
- Migrate the data from the old table to the new table using `Cursor`.
- Drop the old table.

Change the database version to upgrade your table.